# Angular SSR NgApexcharts SVG is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, apexcharts

Originally I was having issues with this package using Angular SSR as I was getting this error on import `Window is not defined`

However, you can mock this in `server.ts` via the following:

```
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();
global.window = mock.getWindow();
```

I'm now getting an error as stated in the title, SVG is not defined. IS there any way to mock this?

I believe it uses `https://github.com/svgdotjs/` under the hood

Thanks

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: https://github.com/apexcharts/ng-apexcharts/issues/112#issuecomment-795324991

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ng-apexcharts`, I still get the `ReferenceError: SVG is not defined` error. So this is what I tried and seems to be working.

1. I'm NOT importing `NgApexchartsModule`
2. template.html

```
<div id="chart" *ngIf="isBrowser"></div>
```

3. component.ts

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: object) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
}

...

if (this.isBrowser) {
    const ApexCharts = require('apexcharts');
    const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), this.options);
    chart.render();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay!